# SQL - Select column value if other value is not present

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query in SQL designed like below:

```
Column A    Column B    Column C
Mary               24             First 
Mary               25             Second
Paul                5             First 
Tim             1             Second
```

I want to return all rows with "First" in column C, and rows with "Second" only if it does not have corresponding "First" value based upon column A. So I'd like to see:

```
Mary 24
Paul 5
Tim 1
```

I've tried Case statements and If statements, but can't get it to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

Here is one trick using `ROW_NUMBER`

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [Column A] ORDER BY [Column C] ASC) RN
FROM TableName
) A
WHERE RN = 1
```

Alphabetically `F` comes before `S` so the row number `1` will be assigned to `First`. If `First` is not present then `1` will be assigned to `Second`

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer will be to use NOT IN.

So, this take all people when Column C = First OR C = Second and they have no other occurence with FIRST)

```
SELECT [Column A], [Column B]
FROM tableName
WHERE [Column C] = 'First'
OR 
([Column C] = 'Second'
AND [Column A] NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT [Column A] 
    FROM tableName 
    WHERE [Column C] = 'First'))
```

I'm not sure it'll be efficient in terms of speed but it's easy to understand.

I can't test by now, so please comment if I did a mistake.

Comment: You're correct, this does work and makes complete sense. But it took quite a while to run it. Thanks!